# SSIS Execute Process Task giving a "The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0" " error when trying to Unzip folder with WinRAR

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to use the "Execute Process Task" in SSIS to unzip a folder but I get the following error:

[Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" "e C:\Users\josh\Desktop\T-SQL_SQL Server\SSIS_RealWorld_Course_Udemy\Section 5 - Project 3\SharedFolder\Data20220703.zip -o+" at "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\T-SQL_SQL Server\SSIS_RealWorld_Course_Udemy\Section 5 - Project 3\Processed", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

SSIS returns a message box which says: Unknown Option ""

and

WinRAR: Diagnostic returns a message box which says: No Archives Found

When I invoke the "Rar.exe" in the "Execute Process Task" I no longer get the two message boxes but it still fails to run.

The new error message is: [Execute Process Task] Error:

In Executing "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" "e C:\Users\josh\Desktop\T-SQL_SQL Server\SSIS_RealWorld_Course_Udemy\Section 5 - Project 3\SharedFolder\Data20220703.zip -o+" at "C:\Users\josh\Desktop\T-SQL_SQL Server\SSIS_RealWorld_Course_Udemy\Section 5 - Project 3\Processed", The process exit code was "7" while the expected was "0".

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'll delete it.

Comment: `WinRAR.exe` is a GUI tool and is probably expecting to be in a desktop session. What happens if you invoke the `rarcmd.exe` command line tool instead? (It's in the same folder.)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I don't see a "rarcmd.exe" in the folder but I do see the "Rar.exe" is that the same?

Comment: It could be. I haven't used the RARlabs tools from SSIS for a number of years now so my memory could be letting me down.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning When I invoke the "Rar.exe" in the "Execute Process Task" I no longer get the two message boxes but it still fails to run. I placed the new error message in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I was getting my original error.

The reason the SSIS Execute Process Task was giving me an error is because I had spaces in my file name. Once I removed the spaces everything worked normally.